# Windows azure disabled due to cache exeeding 128 MB alocated to msdn premium subscription

Tags: azure

I just started to learn windows azure and have I have exceeded the cache limit of 128 MB for my MSDN Premium subscriptions this month and my account have been disabled. I'm trying to figure out what services use cache by default as I looked at usage log and saw that something used about 8 MB per day. I have not done something specific just played around created one web site, two cloud services(but not deployed any packages), one service bus namespace, one sql database, one vm (but un-deployed it after some testing, disk remained on storage account).

My question is what is cause that constant usage of cache space.

Comment: Were you testing locally on your machine and pointing at the Cache in Azure?

Comment: Not even used cache just created some stuff on azure portal a leaved it enabled, after that at the end of this month I have been notified by email that my account have disabled to prevent charging.

Comment: You might want to contact support https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also confused by this and wrote a post about [Azure cache billing](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/azure-appfabric-cache-billing.html) but in summary:

You have assigned a 128MB cache to use each month but since it displays usage as a percentage, 50% implies you have 64MB left to use but it doesn't accumulate like that. Think of 50% to mean you have half a month left to use the cache.

Because you have set up a 128MB cache you are using it - regardless of if you are *actually* using it. It's like compute hours in that respect.

Comment: Anyway why in the billing history for last month per Cache 128MB/month it say that I consumed 136.25 MB of 128MB how can this happen. Previously I saw that on the usage charts on the last few days of the month there was 8 MB/Day rather than 4.13MB